# How do I sudo over sshfs?

Tags: ssh, sudo, sshfs

On my local host `alpha` I have a directory `foo` that is mapped via sshfs to host `bravo` as follows:

```
$ sshfs charlie@bravo:/home/charlie ~/foo
```

However, on host `bravo` there is another user, delta, that I want to `sudo /bin/su` as, so that I can do work in `bravo:/home/delta`. `delta` may not be logged into via ssh; for reasons which I cannot change, you can only sudo over to delta once you're on the machine.

Normally I'd ssh into `bravo`, then sudo to delta, but I'm wondering if there's any way that I can do that when I've got charlie's home dir mounted via ssh.

Comment: This may be best solved with file permissions.

Answer (score 58):

This will vary depending on the OS of the server you are connecting to.  For centOS 5 you would add to the sshfs mount options:

`-o sftp_server="/usr/bin/sudo /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server"`

For Ubuntu 9.10 (I think, might be 9.04, but it's probably the same for both) or Debian you would add:

`-o sftp_server="/usr/bin/sudo /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server"`.

To find an the correct path for other systems running openSSH run

`sudo grep Subsystem /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

and look for the location of the sftp-server binary.

You might need to setup sudo with NOPASS:{path to sftp-server} or prevalidate with `ssh user@host sudo -v` so that `sudo` has a updated timestamp for `notty`.  In my case, my two commands were:

```
ssh login_user@host sudo -v
sshfs login_user@host:remote_path local_path -o sftp_server="/usr/bin/sudo -u as_user /usr/lib/ssh/sftp-server"
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a very neat 'trick'. I just added a "-u <some_other_user>" to the sudo for my situation

Comment: Very good, worked flawlessly. My only point is that there is /usr/bin/sudo twice in the example, which seems unnecessary.

Comment: @Craisis Sorry to bring up old post, but I want to ssh into a CentOS 6.5 server with a basic user, but mount a folder that's root access only. Would this be correct: `sshfs basicuser@remotehost:remote_path local_mount_path -o sftp_server="/usr/bin/sudo -u root /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server"`?

Comment: `ssh host sudo -v` doesn't make my sudo happy - it wants a tty before it lets me sudo. Thoughts?

Comment: @w00t Use `ssh -t host sudo -v` to connect with a pseudo terminal.

Comment: @sebi thanks! Weird, I have been using ssh -t since at least 2001, no idea why I wrote that comment :)

Comment: Minor addition: newer sudo implementations have timestamps tied to the tty as well.  To remedy/workaround, add some form of "Defaults !tty_tickets" to the remote server '/etc/sudoers'.

Comment: Working for me with Android (only way I found to get write access to DCIM folder) with this option: `sftp_server="/system/xbin/su -c /data/data/berserker.android.apps.sshdroid/dropbear/sftp-server"`

Comment: @eggo @Sebi @calandoa @xaralis Do this command work also if I want to sudo as root in debian 9 ? Because if I use:

`ssh -t myuser@host sudo -v
sshfs myuser@host:remote_path local_path -o sftp_server="/usr/bin/sudo -u root /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server"` it doesn't work :\ - it just says "remote hosts has disconnected"

Comment: for me it works with `ssh`, but for sshfs I get `remote host has disconnected` :c

Answer (score 7):

You can use bindfs + sshfs to access other user files (even root).

Firstly you mount your 'root' or any other directory under your user with remapped uid.

`ssh -t USER@SERVER "mkdir ~/tmproot; sudo bindfs --map=root/USER / ~/tmproot"`

and then simply sshfs into the directory.

`sshfs USER@SERVER:tmproot TARGET`

But for security it's better to not map whole root `/` but only part that you need.
For example: You can use this method to mount any other user directory to your, for example files from /var/www into ~/www and remap root into your user so you will have full access to it.

If you need access to preserve uid or have access to multiple users then i would create a new user for example "rootfs" with uid=0 and /bin/false and do a normal sshfs.

Comment: Though this is the best solution IMO, bindfs is not avialable by default on linux systems.

Answer (score 1):

By deduction, I think this is **impossible** to achieve in a simple command.

This is because **sshfs calls ssh without passing any command but, instead, uses SFTP which is a subsystem of SSH.**

From the **sshfs** manpage:

> On the remote computer the SFTP
>   subsystem of SSH is used.

**Plus**, changing the current user (or 'su' or 'sudo') is not part of the SFTP protocol, though this seems like a very often requested feature.

Comment: this is not impossible.  Craisis's solution works.

Comment: Of course yes, since he overrides the command that starts the subsystem and adds sudo. Good finding but you have to set up sudo without a password (or use a timestamp), which may decrease security. but I won't argue since OP really wanted to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You might try (but I don't think it will work):

```
sshfs -o ssh_command='ssh sudo /bin/su bravo' charlie@bravo:/home/charlie ~/foo
```

I don't understand sshfs very well, so you might be able to get something like that to work, but I couldn't say how, and I would be a little surprised.

Another possibility is to put the command 'sudo /bin/su bravo' in ~/.ssh/rc, but that would affect all of your fs mountings (assuming it worked, which I also doubt) as well as your normal use of ssh.

Sorry for being a debbie downer.

Comment: It does not work. The @Craisis's answer is the proper one.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the best way is through file permissions, as @artifex proposes.

As @Weboide says, it is impossible through sshfs.

But I guess you could create a simple script, let's call it `sudossh` that will take your `$PWD`, convert it to `/home/delta/` and run the command through `ssh` and `sudo` on the remote machine.

Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ssh -t charlie@bravo "cd `pwd | sed 's/user\/foo/delta/'`; sudo -u delta $*"
```

After that you can execute `sudossh command` and remember to use relative paths.

If you use ssh-agent, you just have to enter your `sudo` password.

Answer (score 0):

You can `sed` your way into `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to find where `sftp-server` is, and then run it with `sudo`. The advantage of using this is that it will work on servers running different distros, as long as `ssh_config` is in the same place.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
sshfs -o sftp_server='/usr/bin/env sudo "$(sed -nE "/^[[:blank:]]*[Ss][Uu][Bb][Ss][Yy][Ss][Tt][Ee][Mm][[:blank:]]+sftp[[:blank:]]+/{s///;s/[[:blank:]]*(|#.*)$//;p;q}" /etc/ssh/sshd_config)"' "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this universal one-liner:

`sshfs -o sftp_server="/usr/bin/sudo '$(grep sftp-server /etc/ssh/sshd_config | awk -F" " "{print \$3}")' "`

This should be basically equivalent to André Kugland's answer, but more readable. It uses:

1. awk to get the SFTP submodule config line's 3rd column (path):

`grep sftp-server /etc/ssh/sshd_config | awk -F" " "{print \$3}"`

2. single quotes to avoid variable expansion on the client machine

`"/usr/bin/sudo '$(grep sftp-server /etc/ssh/sshd_config | awk -F" " "{print \$3}")' "`