# sshfs mount using sudo'ed account

Tags: linux, sudo, sshfs

We have a linux system ferguson.

On ferguson:

- I have user id a123.
- As user id a123, I am able to `sudo su` into userid admin.
- There is no direct login for the userid admin.
- We have to use our personal userids to `sudo su` into userid admin.

I have a virtual box linux vm on my windows laptop.

- From my laptop's linux vm, I am able to use userid a123 to sshfs mount a123@ferguson.
- I would like to sshfs mount as admin@ferguson.
- But admin@ferguson can only be accessed thro `sudo su`.

How can my laptop's linux vm use userid a123 perform sshfs mount ferguson as admin, using sudo access ?

Comment: host ferguson is a rhel.

Comment: Take a look here: https://serverfault.com/questions/158392/how-do-i-sudo-over-sshfs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming the only reason you can't just directly connect via ssh to `ferguson` as the user `admin` is simply because either no password is set for `admin` or you just simply don't know it. There could be other reasons for this not working, such as no login shell.

The best solution for this is to use SSH keys.

On your Linux VM, if you haven't already, generate a public/private key pair: `$ ssh-keygen -t rsa`. Follow the prompts, and accept the default locations. It is suggested to set a passphrase on the private key to protect it.

You will now have a public key you can use under `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`.

On `ferguson`, change to the `admin` account like you normally do. If the file ~/.ssh/authoized_keys does not exist, you'll need to create it first. Permissions are important, and SSH won't allow access if they're not correct.

```
$ mkdir -p ~/.ssh
$ chmod 0700 ~/.ssh
$ touch ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
$ chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

You will then need to copy your public key into one line in `authorized_keys`. If this file already exists, there will likely be other keys. Put your key on its own line.

You should now be able utilize sshfs as the user `admin`. In fact, if `admin` has a suitable login shell already set (such as `/bin/bash`), you will even be able open an ssh session as `admin`.